# Undefined index: id in AJAX, Code Igniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

when I call a function in AJAX, show message error "Undefined index: id", but if in the view I have one button, It's work, but when I have two buttons show me this error. What's the problem? I need create a array or any solution for this?

```
<tbody>
                <?php foreach ($fotos_concurso as $fotos) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><img width="200" height="200" src="<?php echo base_url('/uploads/'.$fotos['nombre_archivo']); ?>"></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fotos['nombre']; ?></td>
                    <td><a class="aprobar_foto" href="<?= base_url('admin/aprobar_foto') ?>" id="<?php echo $fotos['id'] ?>" title="aprobar"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></td>
                    <td><a class="desaprobar_foto" href="<?= base_url('admin/desaprobar_foto') ?>" id="<?php echo $fotos['id'] ?>" title="desaprobar"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
```

And the AJAX code

```
$('.aprobar_foto').on('click', function() {
            q = $(this);
            if (confirm('¿Quieres aprobar la foto?')) {
                $url = q.attr('href');
                $.ajax({ 
                    type: "post", 
                    url: $url, 
                    cache: false,   
                    data: "id=" + q.attr('id'), 
                    fail: function () { 
                        alert('Ha habido un error al borrar el registro');
                    },
                    success: function (redir) {
                        window.location = redir;
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });

        $('.desaprobar_foto').on('click', function() {
            q = $(this);

            if (confirm('¿Quieres desaprobar la foto?')) {
                $url = q.attr('href');
                $.ajax({ 
                    type: "post", 
                    url: $url, 
                    cache: false,   
                    data: "id=" + q.attr('id'), 
                    fail: function () { 
                        alert('Ha habido un error al borrar el registro');
                    },
                    success: function (redir) {
                        window.location = redir;
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: use inspect element using firebug in browser console to check id value exist. then alert you id in js code.

Answer (score 0):

**Set your id field like this:**

```
var id = q.attr('id');
data: {id: id},
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but once use this type :-

```
var ids = q.attr('id');
data: {id: ids},
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Some approach is wrong like id should be unique in a whole page,if some attribute has id neither any other attribute should be the same id.

2) print_r($fotos_concurso,1); check 'id' index exists or not

3) You can check on console log, each should collect correct "id"

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have this error is probably because you are using SAME ids (#) for both buttons.

Instead of using ID to store your **foto_id** value , use 'data-id'

You can do is give them same class, different href value, and 'data-value'  and 1 common On Click function.

So, your HTML will be like this:

**btn_foto** is common class in both buttons, and instead of **id**, **data-id** is used

```
<tbody>
            <?php foreach ($fotos_concurso as $fotos) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><img width="200" height="200" src="<?php echo base_url('/uploads/'.$fotos['nombre_archivo']); ?>"></td>
                <td><?php echo $fotos['nombre']; ?></td>
                <td><a class="btn_foto" href="<?= base_url('admin/aprobar_foto') ?>" data-id="<?php echo $fotos['id'] ?>" title="aprobar"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></td>
                <td><a class="btn_foto" href="<?= base_url('admin/desaprobar_foto') ?>" data-id="<?php echo $fotos['id'] ?>" title="desaprobar"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
```

and your Ajax Javascript as:

```
$('.btn_foto').on('click', function() {
        q = $(this);
        if (confirm('¿Quieres aprobar la foto?')) {
            $url = q.attr('href');
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "post", 
                url: $url, 
                cache: false,   
                data: "id=" + q.attr('data-id'), 
                fail: function () { 
                    alert('Ha habido un error al borrar el registro');
                },
                success: function (redir) {
                    window.location = redir;
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
```

NOTE: 'data-value' are data attributes and they should be preferred over 'classes' and 'ids' to store values. The  'data-attributes' can be unique or same values, as they dont have any restriction.

Comment: Same error, one of my controller is this

public function aprobar_foto () {
  if (empty($this->data['logged_in']) || ! in_array('fotos_concurso', $this->data['permisos'])) { // redirect them to the login page
   redirect('admin/login', 'refresh');
  }
  $this->data['seccion'] = 'Fotos';
  $this->fotosconcurso->aprobar_foto($_POST['id']);
 }

Comment: As you said, your error is "Undefined index: id"  , then your issue is because of id. If you followed ,my above code, you shouldnt get "Undefined index: id" error atleast.

Make sure:
1) In view you are using 'data-id' instead of 'id'
2) in Javascript: .attr('data-id')  instead of .attr('id')

Comment: It's OK, Just copy your example and still the same error.

Comment: hmm. can you use FireBug and check in Headers, what value is being sent for 'id' ? if its blank you can work on View , if its not blank then issue must be in Controller.